# Javascript event after the dom is ready but not rendered

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to do something after the dom is ready but it is not rendered(White screen)
I would like to hide the contents from user and after some operations i would like to show the final picture. 
I could use "display:none" on my body tag but i am working on a huge project so i dont want to change every page.
Thanks

Comment: I don't get your question, be a bit more clear and What have you tried so far...

Comment: @AurA I think the question is perfectly clear.

Answer (score 3):

Here is how?

```
document.onload = function() {
    //your codes
}
```

Unlike, `window.onload` this function runs after the DOM is loaded, so the manipulation is possible, but it does not require all the elements to be rendered.

Answer (score 2):

> Is it possible to do something after the dom is ready but it is not rendered

Browsers render the DOM incrementally as they parse the HTML into it. The state you describe will not happen naturally.

You can fake it such…

> I could use "display:none" on my body tag but i am working on a huge project so i dont want to change every page.

If you don't want to change every page because it is too much work, then too bad. Go and set up an external stylesheet that every page uses.

If you don't want to change every page because you only want the changes to appear on certain pages, then use a more specific selector.

---

That said, preventing content from displaying and giving users a white screen (or even a loading screen) is just going to turn people off and drive lots of them to another site. I wouldn't recommend doing this.

Answer (score 0):

if you could use JQuery this one is called when the dom is ready but the page not loaded

```
$(document).ready(function(){

)};
```

Comment: Did you see this tagged `jquery` somehow? Please Javascript is not jQuery, but jQuery is.

Comment: ^ Maybe the OP didn't know he/she could use JQuery for this, or just forgot to tag JQuery in the post. You shouldn't discourage users from posting legitimate solutions with your own assumptions. With that said, this function won't work because some parts of the DOM may already rendered, resulting in a flashing effect. (Sorry, I know this post is really old, but this kind of comment on SO drives me nuts).

Answer (score 0):

I'll contribute my own 2 cents here.

With jquery, the $("document").ready() event fires after the DOM has been fully loaded(without images, that is) to your browser, but not displayed. So I think to achieve what you want, you'll have to input some handler function inside the ".ready()" method to handle whatsoever you desire to achieve.

Is that what you were looking for?